# How can I view a boost::optional in the CLion debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clion, boost-optional

The built-in GDB in CLion shows a boost::optional as a char array. How can I teach it to show the contents as the real type?

[image: boost optional in clion gdb debugger]

Comment: As with any GDB you need a "printer" to show complex structures, like this one: https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer

Comment: @oakad That works, thanks, you can make this an answer.

Comment: I haven't made an answer in years. :-D

Comment: @oakad why not? This question is answered